# Is it possible to Import Data from Excel to jQGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid-asp.net

Is it possible to import data from an Excel file to jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I had a look at this example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET) but it does not exactly talk about importing data from an excel file. I tried to work around it but the data is not being displayed on the jqGrid. All I get is an empty table with headers only. Any help would be great :)

My View Code: jQGrid:

```
<table id="jQGridDemo"></table>
<div id="jQGridDemoPager"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
    url: 'TopPlayedInVenueList',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department',
            'Age'],
    colModel: [
    { name: '_id', index: '_id', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
    { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
    { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150 },
       { name: 'LastSSN', index: 'LastSSN', width: 100 },
    { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 80, align: "right" },
    { name: 'Age', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" }
],
    rowNum: 10,
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "List Employee Details"
});
</script>
```

My Controller Code:

```
public JsonResult TopPlayedInVenueList()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                string Path = @"C:\\1.xls";

                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [All$A2:Z]", con);

                //OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [All$]", con);

                con.Close();

                System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();

                da.Fill(data);

                List<TopPlayedInVenue> daa = new List<TopPlayedInVenue>();

                foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayedInVenue top = new TopPlayedInVenue()
                    {
                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name")
                    };

                    daa.Add(top);
                }



                var newlist = daa.OrderBy(i => i.TrackName).ToList();

                return Json(daa);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And if you debug your code what do you see? First thing I see is that you are closing the connection before calling the Fill() method, not sure if this could be a problem.

Comment: Also, try to do a simpler select... not using ranges... just to see if this could be the problem.

Comment: @Romias - thanks for your input and I have cleaned the code :) - also did a simple select just to check but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code and i got exception about **[All$A2:Z]**

Also tried to found answer but looks like query is not working.

Try to access each Sheet by name in loop.

```
string Path = @"E:\\DemoXls.xls";
        var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");

        con.Open();
        DataTable mySheets = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        con.Close();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        var query = "Select * from [{0}]";
        foreach (DataRow item in mySheets.Rows)
        {
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format(query, item["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            da.Fill(dt);
            //DO the mapping of DataTable to your List<T>   
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I tried your code and it seems to be working but not displaying any data to the jQGrid. Could it be issue with the linking url? `url: '@Url.Action("TopPlayedInVenueList", "ReportStatistic")',` Is that the right way?

Comment: @Url.Action should work.
Also I Can that see your column name in Java Script code is not matching with `TopPlayedInVenue ` properties which you are using.
you are expecting FirstName,LastName,LastSSN,Department and Salary in JS Code but your action is returning TrackName and ArtistName.
Can you check this